# Installing Gtest using CMake

Tags: macos, cmake, googletest

I am trying to install `GTest` using `CMake` on `MacOS`. I am getting the following error:

```
cmake -G "Makefiles" ..
```

Error: CMake Error: `Could not create named generator Makefiles`

Answer (score 1):

try `cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' ..`

see http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#section_Generators